# How to prevent VS Code from collapsing a trailing empty line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a habit of using code editors for notes in the following fashion:

```
a topic
. a note
 ? a question regarding the note
  - a to do item
 . some more details
. another note
 . more details

another topic
...
```

What I like about VS Code is that it allows to fold (collapse) blocks in txt files based on their indentation (like for Python):

```
  a topic
+ . a note
  . another note
   . more details

  another topic
  ...
```

What I don't like, though, is that it also includes empty lines into collapsed blocks: the line after `. more details` has no indentation, but when I collapse that block I get

```
  a topic
+ . a note
+ . another note
  another topic
  ...
```

while I want it to be

```
  a topic
+ . a note
+ . another note

  another topic
  ...
```

Can you suggest what options should I change to get this difference about collapsing?

Comment: I am similarly annoyed with SQL.  It doesn't do it for all languages so maybe its somewhere in the language definition file.

Comment: VScode doesn't do that to me. What os & version are you using?

Comment: Doesn't do that for me either.  You code try setting the `Folding Strategy` to `indentation`.  And yes, if you have that set to `auto` it will use the folding strategy contributed by the language service, if there is one.  What is your language?  It works for me in a `.txt` file with the folding strategy set to `indentation` or `auto` (probably because `auto` falls back to `indentation` in `.txt` files).

Comment: @Andoo , Mark, yeah thanks, the problem doesn't seem to exist in the latest version of VS Code, but if anybody explains how to solve the issue of blindguy, I'll accept that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to prevent the last line from being folded in VS Code, unless you use a 3rd party extension.

If you [search extensions for 'folding'](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=folding&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) you should see several. [Explicit Folding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zokugun.explicit-folding) appears to have options to control this. But there are a lot more. Take a look & see if one fits your needs. If not then the only way to get this would be to develop an extension to handle this the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

While not an ideal, a quick and dirty solution that one can use today is to set custom ranges: in the example above,

```
  . another note
   . more details

  another topic
```

put the cursor after "note" and select the text to the end of "details", then press `ctrl+k`, `ctrk+,` ("Create Folding Range from Selection"). The result will be

```
+ . another note

  another topic
```

as needed; the obvious downside is that one has to create such ranges manually. But if you have not that much problematic blocks, it can be good enough (at least it's quick and doesn't require any plugins).